# Svelte error after build in console: 'App is not defined'

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup

I am developing an application using Svelte with Rollup and I ran into such a problem that when I compile it gives me a warning about the absence of App:

```
 No name was provided for external module 'C:\...path...\App.svelte' in output.globals – guessing 'App'
```

The console displays at startup:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at main.js:5
```

My Rollup config:
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Xc5hYkRh)

main.js:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body
});

export default app;
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `external` setting in your Rollup config. You are passing a `builtins` function from `rollup-plugin-node-builtins`. Since this function returns a truthy value, Rollup assumes that every module you import is external.

> The external key accepts either an array of module names, or a function which takes the module name and returns true if it should be treated as external.

See the Rollup documentation on [external](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#peer-dependencies).

You need to pass an array here with the modules you want treated as external. Are you intending to pass a [builtin-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/builtin-modules) import here instead? I found this example in the [rollup-plugin-node-resolve README](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve#resolving-built-ins-like-fs).

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import builtins from 'builtin-modules'
export default ({
  input: ...,
  plugins: [resolve()],
  external: builtins,
  output: ...
})
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer a little. Sorry, I'm not very good at working with the Rollup configuration, can you tell us more?

Comment: If you take out the “external” line in your config the build works. Can you tell me why you added that line in the first place? Or if you get a different error after removing that line?